# Starting Pure PHP socket in Backend/Asynchronously

Tags: php, sockets, asynchronous

> I have created a php socket for my ios app. and it is working perfectly when i am starting it using terminal before doing all the work..
>
> The problem was the *first* socket_write.

Before writing, check if the socket of the server was running.. `$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);`

If `false` i need to redirect to the page `http://localhost/api3/server.php` to start the socket

```
public function __socket_write($text)
{
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);

    if ($result === false) 
    {
        // if failed to connect means the server is currently down/not running
        $this->__socket_start("http://localhost/api3/server.php");
    }
    // codes here not called api got an time out error as well, must have been    redirected completely?
}

public function __socket_start($url, $status_code = 303)
{
   header('Location: '.$url, true, $status_code);
}
```

the server was successfully started but it looks like i need to call `__socket_start()` asynchronously to be able to execute the codes below `$this->__socket_start()` but i don't know how, and after a while the socket from server was closed again...

When i start the socket using the terminal `php server.php`, it doesn't disconnect.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, it is not the one that i really want to do, but it's working now properly like what i intended to do from the first place..

Here is how i looks now:

```
public function __socket_write($text)
{
    $service_port = xxxxxx;

    $address = MyAddress;

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);

    if ($result === false) 
    {
        $this->__socket_start();
    } 

    @socket_listen($socket);

    ...

    socket_close($socket);
}

public function __socket_start()
{
    $cmd = "php server.php";

    shell_exec($cmd." > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
}
```